# JMeter XPath results are missing expected items

Tags: xpath, jmeter

Using XPath assertion: `//ul/@class` after a HTTP request, the assertion returns:

```
success_message_1=links
success_message_2=accordion vertnav vertnav-top grid-full
success_message_3=grid-full classic
success_message_4=checkout-types
success_message_5=links
success_message_matchNr=5
```

It is missing exactly one element, which happens to be the success message I need to find. The structure of the success message is:

`<ul class="messages"><li class="success-msg"><ul><li>Message</li></ul></li></ul>`

Strangely targeting the item with `//li[@class="success-msg"]` returns nothing. Using jQuery I did a simple `jQuery('ul')` and it matches all of the `<ul>` including the missing one.

I've checked the response and the success message does exist in the response, but why can't I select it with XPath?

Comment: You should post the complete response, because based on your post (without the complete response) it is hard to see how it could go wrong.

Comment: @ljgw I didn't post it as it is for an internal program. I'm looking for areas I can look at, including other XPath testers. I've tried an online one and it worked. Not sure what else I can check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct XPath expression if you need to obtain "Message" "vanilla" XPath selector will look like

```
//li[@class='success-msg']/ul/li/text()
```

If your page is not XML/XHTML compliant you may require to enable "Use Tidy" box in your XPath Assertion.

Particularly for your code following XPath Assertion works for me:

```
//li/text()='Message'
```

You may wish to use [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) combiner with [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to see what is the output of your XPath queries and once you'll get "true" - the query is OK to be used in the assertion.

Comment: Thanks, none of those work - I think this is a JMeter issue because my xpath works with a any other external xpath debugger. I've attached a sample response to the question.